# Port and RmiPort on JBoss NamingService

Tags: rmi, jndi, jboss5.x

On JBoss 5, there is the NamingService, which lets you specify the properties `Port` (1099 by default) and `RmiPort` (1098 by default). I've never needed to know how this works before now, it has always Just Worked™.

How are these ports used? Is `Port` used to find objects in JNDI and then `RmiPort` used to invoke them, or do they both provide different approaches for invoking the same methods on the same classes?

Comment: I have the same question for JBoss 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `Port` is the port of the rmi registry, and `RmiPort` the port where the connections are made